# Share DataSet between Forms

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable, dataset

I'm working on a Windows form application in Visual Studio 2010 Express. My Home form has one dataset with 4 tables. One of these tables is called "Category" and I want to manage this table from a separate form called Categories.

I followed the steps outlined by @Harm van der Haas in ([Shared DataSet Over Multiple Forms C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11634617/shared-dataset-over-multiple-forms-c-sharp/11635190#11635190)) but I can't get it work.

In my *Home* form I have the following code:

```
public partial class frmHome : Form
{
    public DataSet _dsMain;

    public frmHome(DataSet dsMain)
    {
        _dsMain = dsMain;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

And in my program.cs I have:

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        DataSet DS = new DataSet();
        Application.Run(new frmHome(DS));
    }
}
```

And in my *Category* form I have the following code:

```
public partial class frmCategory : Form
{
    public DataSet ds2;
    public frmCategory(DataSet dsMain)
    {
        ds2 = dsMain;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void frmCategory_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dgvCategory.DataSource = ds2;
        dgvCategory.DataMember = "Category";
        dgvCategory.Refresh();
    }
}
```

Here I launch the form Category:

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Globals.startTime = DateTime.Now;
    frmCategory frmC = new frmCategory(_dsMain);
    frmC.ShowDialog();
    //updateActiveTrans();
}
```

But when the Category form loads my datagridview on it `dgvCategory` doesn't show Category tables headers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. I was passing the DataSet incorrectly from my home form. This is the code that ended up working for me.

In my home(main) form I created the constructor like so:

```
public partial class frmHome : Form
{
    public frmHome(DataSet dsMain)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

In my *Program.cs* I did the following:

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    DataSet DS = new DataSet();
    Application.Run(new frmHome(DS));
```

And this is how I open my Category form. --the form where I need to remotely view and manage a table from my dsMain DataSet--

```
    frmCategory frmC = new frmCategory(dsMain);
    frmC.ShowDialog();
```

And in my Category form I passed my *dsMain* declared in my home form, I declared a new public DataSet *ds2* and made it equal to *dsMain*.

```
public partial class frmCategory : Form
{
    public DataSet ds2;
    public frmCategory(DataSet dsMain)
    {
        ds2 = dsMain;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

And finally in my form load event I bound *ds2* to my dataGridView like so:

```
private void frmCategory_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dgvCategory.DataSource = ds2;
    dgvCategory.DataMember = "Category";
    dgvCategory.Refresh();
```

And it works like a charm now. I can view, edit and save my main DataSet from my Category form now. Thanks for the help @CharlesMighty, it helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

in you frmCategory_Load event when assigning the grid a datasource you need to specify the table that you need.  Here is the sample code:

```
public partial class frmCategory : Form
{
public DataSet ds2;
public frmCategory(DataSet dsMain)
{
    ds2 = dsMain;
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void frmCategory_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dgvCategory.DataSource = ds2.Tables[0]; //you can use .Tables[1] or the desired table
    dgvCategory.DataMember = "Category";
    dgvCategory.Refresh();
}
```

}

Comment: That doesn't appear to work. The Category table is the third table in my dsMain dataset so I tried both _3_ and _"Category"_ but it didn't make a difference.         `private void frmCategory_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dgvCategory.DataSource = ds2.Tables[3];
            dgvCategory.DataMember = "Category";
            dgvCategory.Refresh();
        }`

Comment: delete the code dgvCategory.DataMember = "Category";

Answer (score 1):

Here is my simple way on how to pass `Dataset` from one form to another. I'm using **Visual Studio 2012 C# WPF** with **PostgreSQL** as Database.

```
        //ON MY FIRST FORM
        //this is my connection - add it anywhere you want
        //or change it according to your need
        NpgsqlConnection iConnect = new NpgsqlConnection("Server = " + myModule.Server + ";Port = " + myModule.Port + ";User ID = " + myModule.UserID + ";Password = " + myModule.Password + ";Database = " + myModule.Database);
        iConnect.Open();
        NpgsqlCommand iQuery = new NpgsqlCommand("Select * from Table1");
        iQuery.Connection = iConnect;
        NpgsqlDataAdapter iAdapter = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(iQuery);
        DataSet iDataSet = new DataSet();
        iAdapter.Fill(iDataSet, "SET");

        myModule.dtSet = iDataSet;//pass the dataset to myModule.cs
```

Then, click **Project**>>**Add Class**>>and rename it to **myModule.cs**

Then add the following code inside **class myModule**

```
        //This is the code for the DATASET shared
        static DataSet strDataset;
        //this is the catcher of DATASET info request...
        public static DataSet dtSet
        {
           get { return strDataset; }
           set { strDataset = value; }
        }
```

Now, this is how you will use the passed dataset on your second form.

```
    //MY SECOND FORM
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataSet iDataSet = new DataSet();//set the instance of Dataset
        iDataSet = myModule.dtSet;       //get the data from myModule and pass it to iDataSet

    //now, you can use it here!
    }
```

That's it and happy coding! ^_^